# C# Xamarin Action after SetContentView

Tags: c#, function, xamarin, action, setcontentview

I am struggling with something...

I created a ListView bound with an adapter, and added a ClickListener to the ListView. When I click on a row, it loads a page (axml) with:

```
private void InfoTab_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set view to Info page
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Info);
}
```

Now I want to do something after I set the ContentView to the info page, because I want to fill the TextView fields with values from a List, but how can I start a class manually after the SetContentView, because now when I click... Nothing happens!!!

Please help me, I'm a beginner with Xamarin ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. But you can populate the contents of a page/layout in the following way:

```
var textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.yourLayoutIdHere);
textView.Text = "Hello world";
```

You might want consider to create a new activity in which you display the new page. It will handle navigation via back button and other things automatically for you. you can create a new Activity like so:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(NewActivityClass));
StartActivity(intent);
```